Sharing excel sheet with users protections
im trying to share to a team in sharepoint Excel where I have names of my employees. I want them to see only a table where is their name filtered and they cannot see any others collegues data in a table. For example if i have a collegue name Peter Parker, if he open that excel workbook he would see a table only with a filtered data Peter Parker and he can edit that. He wouldnt see whole table, only I when im admin of that workbook. And similar with other employees. Is it possible to do it in Excel SharePoint ?

I would approach this differently by giving each team member their own sheet with an agreed password.
Then you have a summary sheet which accesses each individual sheet.

Sorry, SharePoint currently does not have a way to assign permissions to the content in a file. The smallest unit for assigning permissions in SharePoint is a file or an item in a list.
